# Button is unclickable - possible causes?

Tags: html, css

I've made a button for my page, but it is not clickable. The pointer doesn't even appear. Why does it happen? How can I fix it?

Also, did I center the .intro and #more correctly? I feel like there is a better way than this which would also be more responsive, but I'm not sure. Some tips would be great!

Thanks a lot.

```css
/*Continut centru*/

#continut {
    padding-top: 250px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    user-select: none;
    pointer-events: none; 
}

#intro {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #77dff1;
    font-size: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}

.intro {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 30px;
}

/*Buton MORE*/

#more {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: transparent;
    border: #77dff1 2px solid;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="continut">
            <h1 id="intro">hi</h1>
            <h6 class="intro">asdf</h6>>
                <button type="button" href="#" id="more">More...</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Remove the extra `>` from the `<h6></h6>` tags for a start.

Comment: pointer-events: none; // disable all pointer events

Comment: Also, the `href` attribute is redundant (and invalid) for `<button>`

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you!

Answer (score 1):

Your parent div `#continut` has `pointer-events` as `none` and that's the reason the default mouse-event of `button` to is `none`, to override you could you `!important` rules.

```css
/*Continut centru*/

#continut {
  padding-top: 250px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#intro {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #77dff1;
  font-size: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

.intro {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 30px;
}


/*Buton MORE*/

#more {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: transparent;
  border: #77dff1 2px solid;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  pointer-events: auto !important;
  /* Add this */
}
```

```html
<div id="continut">
  <h1 id="intro">hi</h1>
  <h6 class="intro">asdf</h6>
  <button type="button" href="#" id="more">More...</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to add `!important` to override cascades. In fact, !important should be the very last thing to ever do.

Comment: @René Then what would be the other way of adding default button feature.

Comment: The same without `!important`. !important is only relevant if you need to change something on the element itself. To override the behaviour inherited from the parent it's unnecessary.

Comment: @René Agree on use of !important rule, but till OP won't update what it was trying I can't update with other solution. As a suggestion it could individually style it's child element, instead of adding pointer-events:none to parent.

Comment: Yeah, I set pointer-events:none on the children and it still doesn't work. I've even deleted it entirely and it still doesn't. oh nevermind it does

Answer (score 1):

```css
/*Continut centru*/

#continut {
    padding-top: 250px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    user-select: none;
}

#intro {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #77dff1;
    font-size: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}

.intro {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 30px;
}

/*Buton MORE*/

#more {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: transparent;
    border: #77dff1 2px solid;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="continut">
            <h1 id="intro">hi</h1>
            <h6 class="intro">asdf</h6>>
                <button type="button" href="#" id="more">More...</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I think so, I forgot if I solved it using the answer above or yours. Anyway I've thanked you for your effort :)

Comment: you probably should find whitch one solved your problem and give him the verify signe :)